# invoke anchor onclick from window onload in asp.net for firefox:-

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html

I have 2 files :- Parent.aspx and Child.aspx

Parent.aspx is given below:-

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="Parent.aspx.vb" Inherits="oneNetASP.Parent"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1">
        <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" content="Visual Basic .NET 7.1">
        <meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript">
        <meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function(event) 
        {
            if (window.event)   // IE
            {
                document.getElementById("linkid").click();  
            } 
            else
            {                       
                document.getElementById("linkid").onclick();    
            }                   
        }

        function doOnClick()
        {           
            document.getElementById("linkid").href = 'Child.aspx';      
        }
        </script>
    </HEAD>
    <body>
        <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
            <a id="linkid" href="" onclick="doOnClick();">Next Page</a>
        </form>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

Child.aspx is given below :-

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="Child.aspx.vb" Inherits="oneNetASP.Child"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1">
        <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" content="Visual Basic .NET 7.1">
        <meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript">
        <meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">       
    </HEAD>
    <body>
        Hello, How r u?
    </body>
</HTML>
```

When i run the Parent.aspx in IE, it automatically loads the Child.aspx page.
But in Firefox, it dont call the Child.aspx page when i run the Parent.aspx page. But if i click the link on the parent.aspx page it loads the child.aspx page.

Please help me to load the Child.aspx page when i run the Parent.aspx page in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload=function(event)
        {
           if (window.event)       // IE
           {
              document.getElementById("linkid").click();      
           }
           else
           {    
               var clickedElement = document.getElementById("linkid");  

                if (typeof clickedElement.onclick == "function")
                {
                    clickedElement.onclick.apply(clickedElement);
                }
            }                                      
         }
```